# Libvirt dnsmasq is running on all interfaces, this is undesired

Tags: virtualization, kvm, libvirt

So currently I'm running libvirt on my debian box, and it's DHCP server is listening on all interfaces, I would like to restrict that down to the bridge interface where the VMs would live. I can kill off the dhcp server temporarily to accomplish what I need but would like something more permanent.

I'm sure there is some option I can put in the dhcp server portion of the network config to make this happen.

```
<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>2fb34907-96bc-4af1-89a2-4f1f872a2600</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'/>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:c3:d2:ea'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:21:df:dc' ip='192.168.122.2'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
  <route address='192.168.122.2' prefix='32' gateway='192.168.122.110'/>
</network>
```

```
root@calypso-deb:~# lsof -i -n | grep dnsmasq
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    3u  IPv4   29150      0t0  UDP *:bootps 
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    5u  IPv4   29153      0t0  UDP 192.168.122.1:domain 
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    6u  IPv4   29154      0t0  TCP 192.168.122.1:domain (LISTEN)
root@calypso-deb:~#
```

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a suggestion (which is meant to be a comment rather than an answer, but I cannot comment).

User [Jonathon Reinhart](https://serverfault.com/users/55544/jonathon-reinhart) posted [an answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/840163/custom-dnsmasq-or-custom-options-with-libvrt/992164#992164) that describes how to pass options to dnsmasq (since libvirt v.5.6.0). See also [“Network XML format”](https://www.libvirt.org/formatnetwork.html#elementsNamespaces) in the libvirt documentation. This got me wondering whether passing something like `--interface=virbr0 --bind-interfaces` would do what you need in this case.

Answer (score 0):

It should already be listening on `virbr0` interface only, as the config shows that too.

You can check that with `lsof -i -n | grep dnsmasq` or similar tools.

Comment: ```
root@calypso-deb:~# lsof -i -n | grep dnsmasq
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    3u  IPv4   29150      0t0  UDP *:bootps 
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    5u  IPv4   29153      0t0  UDP 192.168.122.1:domain 
dnsmasq     1656       nobody    6u  IPv4   29154      0t0  TCP 192.168.122.1:domain (LISTEN)
root@calypso-deb:~#
```

whomp whomp

Comment: 192.168.122.1:domain (LISTEN)
that's it

Comment: That's DNS, DHCP is bootps